# unable to spawn process '/usr/bin/touch' (Exec format error)

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, xcode11.4

[image]

Strange error encountered. I never faced this issue while building iOS project in Xcode.
Is anyone have any idea about this about how to solve this problem.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for response on this. How to do these changes, any guide? I researched but could not find any.

Comment: I am not coding anything in Xcode, It is Ionic Cordova Project. I deployed many Apps till now. This error occurred without any mess with anything. I did research on this error but could not find any. I am not sure about how this NSTask which you are talking about is done. Can you brief me with steps. That will be really appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea how this question ended up in my feed, and I can't really help you.  I'll go ahead and delete my comments.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be what yo want. But I ran into the same issue where xcode was complaining it can't spawn a process where it was trying to invoke a shell script. In my case, I was using react-native

The following helped for me. Hoping it will do for others who stumble upon this question as well.

change `#/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/sh`

https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config/issues/342#issuecomment-478015709